# HMM for solving given coin output

Tags: algorithm, probability, bioinformatics, hidden-markov-models

I have got this assignment question on HMM and I have solved it. I would like to know if I am correct. The problem is:

> Suppose a dishonest dealer has two coins, one fair and one biased; the biased coin
>   has heads probability 1/4. Assume that the dealer never switches the coins. Which
>   coin is more likely to have generated the sequence `HTTTHHHTTTTHTHHTT`? It may
>   be useful to know that log<sub>2</sub>(3) = 1.585

I calculated the P for fair coin and biased coin.
The P for fair coin is 7.6*10<sup>-6</sup> where as P for biased coin is 3.43*10<sup>-6</sup>. I didn't use log term, which can be used if I solve it the other way. So, I concluded that it is more likely that the given sequence is generated by a fair coin.

Am I right?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the prior probability that the dealer chooses the biased or unbiased coin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you are given the following.

```
P(H|Fake) = 1/4 P(T|Fake) = 3/4
P(H|Fair) = 1/2 P(T|Fair) = 1/2
P(Fair) = 1/2 P(Fake) = 1/2
```

To answer the question you need to answer `P(Fake/HTTTHHHTTTTHTHHTT)` and `P(Fair/HTTTHHHTTTTHTHHTT)` for which you need to apply bayes:

Let `X` be `HTTTHHHTTTTHTHHTT`

```
P(Fake|X) = (P(X|Fake) * P(Fake)) / P(X)
P(Fair|X) = (P(X|Fair) * P(Fair)) / P(X)
```

Where

```
P(X) = P(X|Fake) * P(Fake) + P(X|Fair) * P(Fair)
P(X) = (3.43710e-6 * 0.5) + (7.629e-6 * 0.5) = 5.533e-6
```

And therefore

```
P(Fake|X) = (3.43710e-6 * 0.5) / 5.533e-6 = 0.3106
P(Fair|X) = (7.629e-6 * 0.5) / 5.533e-6 = 0.6894
```

So therefore, **is more likely that the used coin is the FAIR one**. Even though intuitively one might think that the selected coin is the Fake it seems that this is not the case. The given distribution is closer to 0.5 tail 0.5 heads than to 0.25 heads 0.75 tails. For example, in the case of  tails 10/17 is 0.58 that is closer to `P(T|Fair)=.5` than to `P(T|Fake)=.75`

Answer (score 1):

HMM is a bit of an overkill for this example. The probability of getting heads in binomially distributed, with `p = 0.5` for the fair coin and `p = 0.25` for the other one. For both of them, the number of trials `n = 17` (if my counting is correct). From the 17 samples you got 7 successes (7 heads). Using Wolfram Alpha, the probability of the fair coin generating this sample is [approx 0.15](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%20n=17%20p=0.5), as opposed to [approx 0.07](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%20n=17%20p=0.25) for the unfair coin. Note I did not bother calculating the exact numbers, just looked at the plots. The formula is there for you to work with if you want to.

EDIT
If you absolutely must use a HMM, set the set of hidden states to be {fair; unfair} . The transition probabilities are: from a hidden state "fair" to a hidden state "fair"= 1, from a fair to unfair 0, etc, because the dealer is not allowed to change coins halfway through the trial. The emission probability from a hidden state "fair" are 0.5 for observable state "heads" and 0.5 for observable state "tails" (0.25 and 0.75 from "unfair"). You can assume at time `t=0` hidden state "fair" and "unfair" are equally likely.

Comment: your intuition is wrong just because the fake coin has more probabilities of showing tails that doesn't mean that that is the coin used. Actually, 10/17 is closer to .5 than to .75 therefore intuitively the fair coin is the one used.

Comment: @msalvadores Is it not the same answer as yours? The P for fair is 0.15 than P for biased coin which is approx. 0.07. So, the P for fair coin is more and hence it is used and not biased one.

Comment: I refer to the part where you say "Also, you can think about it intuitively- the unfair coin has a higher probability of coming out tails, and out of a sample of 17 you got 10 tails" This might give the wrong impression.

Comment: Now that you have mentioned it, 10/17 is indeed closer to 0.5. Please disregard that part of the answer :)